# How can I return 2 decimals if they end in 0

Tags: jinja2, decimal, rounding

How can I return two decimals if the number ends in 0? What I am using now returns two decimals only if the last number is >0 (i.e., 60.58). Two decimals aren't returned if decimal ends in 0. (I.e., 50.80 returns as 50.8)

Here is what I am using `${{ |float|round(2) }}`

Answer (score 1):

I understand your query relates to showing values in jinja template. This expression in your jinja template show the zero at the end:

```
{{ "%.2f"|format(your_variable) }}
```

So, if the value of `your_variable` is `123.4000`, the template will show as `123.40`.

Comment: Would any  of the builtin filters listed here work? https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#logic